# Testando Metodos Mágicos em PHP UNIT

Tags: php, testes-de-unidade, slim, phpunit, slimframework

Olá. Preciso testar os métodos mágicos em PHP UNIT.
Estou utilizando o framework Slim Framework

Que são eles

```
__set()
__get()
__construct()
__invoke()
handle()
```

Comment: Você sabe o que cada um faz?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13148669/unit-testing-magic-methods

Comment: Não basta fazer o uso como se fosse usar em uma aplicação real, já que teste unitário geralmente espera o comportamento de execução como seria feito na aplicação, mas com todas possibilidades, então o teste para __set seria fazer algo como `$obj->foo = true`? Não é mesmo? Ou me enganei?

Comment: Sei oque cada um faz, agora os testes unitarios em phpunit estão dificeis.